# Leap year C program

Tags: c

Can I please get a little help with this program:

> C program that will repeatedly ask the user to enter a year. The program will then display if the year is a leap year or not. But when the user doesn't want to enter another year, the program will then display all the years entered and will write if the year is leap or not.

Here's what I've done:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int leapYear (int year)
{
    if ((year % 4 == 0 && year % 100 != 0) || year % 400 == 0)
        printf("%d is a leap year\n", year);
    else
        printf("%d is not a leap year\n", year);
    return 0;
}



int main()
{
    int y, ch, i;

    do
        {
            printf("Enter your choice \n 1. Enter a year\n 2. Exit\n ");
            scanf("%d", &ch);          
            switch (ch)
            {
                case 1:
                    printf("Enter a year: "); scanf("%d", &y);
                    leapYear(y);
                    break;
                case 2:
                    exit(0);
            }
        } while (1);
}
```

What I cannot get right is the part where the user wants to exit and I need to display all the years entered and will write if the year is leap or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Linked list may be useful.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct node_tag {
    int year;
    struct node_tag* next;
} node;

int leapYear (int year)
{
    if ((year % 4 == 0 && year % 100 != 0) || year % 400 == 0)
        printf("%d is a leap year\n", year);
    else
        printf("%d is not a leap year\n", year);
    return 0;
}



int main()
{
    int y, ch; /* i was unused, so I deleted it */
    node *head = NULL;
    node **tail = &head;

    do
        {
            printf("Enter your choice \n 1. Enter a year\n 2. Exit\n ");
            scanf("%d", &ch);          
            switch (ch)
            {
                case 1:
                    printf("Enter a year: "); scanf("%d", &y);
                    *tail = (node*)malloc(sizeof(node));
                    (*tail)->year = y;
                    (*tail)->next = NULL;
                    tail = &(*tail)->next;
                    leapYear(y);
                    break;
                case 2:
                    while (head != NULL) {
                        node *next = head->next;
                        leapYear(head->year);
                        free(head);
                        head = next;
                    }
                    exit(0);
            }
        } while (1);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Few modifications to your program

```
        #include <stdio.h>
        #include <stdlib.h>

        /* A custom data type for storing results */
        typedef struct {
                int year;
                int isleap;
        }years_t;

        int leapYear (int year)
        {
                if ((year % 4 == 0 && year % 100 != 0) || year % 400 == 0) {
                        printf("%d is a leap year\n", year);
                        return 0;
                }
                printf("%d is not a leap year\n", year);
                return -1;
        }



        int main()
        {
                int  ch, i = 0;
                years_t y[100] ; // Will use this data type instead of simple int
                int continue_loop = 1;
                do
                {
                        printf("Enter your choice \n 1. Enter a year\n 2. Exit\n ");
                        scanf("%d", &ch);
                        switch (ch)
                        {
                                case 1:
                                        printf("Enter a year: "); scanf("%d", &y[i].year);
                                        y[i].isleap = leapYear(y[i].year); // Keep track of each input with result
                                        i ++;
                                        break;
                                case 2:
                                        continue_loop = 0; // Lets not exit 
                                        break;
                        }


                } while (continue_loop);

    /** Summary at the ent **/
                for ( ch = 0; ch < i ; ch ++ ) {
                        printf("%d %s\n", y[ch].year, ( y[ch].isleap == 0 ) ? "Leap Year" : "Not Leap Year" );
                }

return 0; 

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option using **malloc()** and **realloc()**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int leapYear (int year)
{
    if ((year % 4 == 0 && year % 100 != 0) || year % 400 == 0)
        printf("%d is a leap year\n", year);
    else
        printf("%d is not a leap year\n", year);
    return 0;
}



int main()
{
    int y, ch, i;
/**/ int cnt = 0;
/**/ int *leapyr_ptr;
/**/ int *temp;
/**/ leapyr_ptr = (int *) malloc(cnt);
    do
        {
            printf("Enter your choice \n 1. Enter a year\n 2. Exit\n ");
            scanf("%d", &ch);
            switch (ch)
            {
                case 1:
                    printf("Enter a year: "); scanf("%d", &y);
/**/ cnt++;
/**/ leapyr_ptr = (int *) realloc(leapyr_ptr, cnt);
//you may want to check the return code of realloc for error handling
/**/ temp  = leapyr_ptr;
/**/ i = 0;
/**/ i = 0;
/**/ while(i<cnt-1)
/**/ {
/**/ temp++;
/**/ i++;
/**/ }
/**/ *temp = y;

                    leapYear(y);
                    break;
                case 2:
/**/ temp = leapyr_ptr;
/**/ i = 0;
/**/ while(i<cnt)
/**/ {
/**/ leapYear(*temp);
/**/ temp++;
/**/ i++;
/**/ }
                    exit(0);
            }
        } while (1);
}
```

Comment: What kind of indentation is that?!? Please fix the indentation so that the code is easily readable.

Comment: @CoolGuy, this indentation I kept intentionally to let user know the added lines to the original question asked. The purpose here is to let user know the difference in the code which I made in original program (asked by @curieuse).

Answer (score 0):

What you need is dynamic memory allocation as you haven't got any clue how many years the user will enter.

---

Firstly, you need a pointer to allocate memory. Since what you're going to store are `int`s, you need a pointer to an `int`:

```
int* years; /* Lets name it 'years' */
```

Now, we need a variable to keep track of how much memory we've allocated:

```
int size = 10;
```

Why have I initialized `size` to 10? Because we'll firstly allocate memory for 10 `int`s.

Now, allocating memory dynamically is done by a function called `malloc` from `stdlib.h`. Here is how you should `malloc` `years`:

```
years = malloc(sizeof(int) * size); /* Or years = malloc(size * sizeof *years); */
```

We've allocated memory for `size`(10) `int`s. Was the memory allocation successful? Memory allocation will be unsuccessful when `malloc` returns `NULL` (and `NULL` is pointed to by `years`). So, Lets check it:

```
if(years == NULL) /* If malloc failed */
{
    printf("malloc failed to allocate memory");
    return -1; /* Exit from main */
}
```

Now that you've allocated memory, we can write to the allocated memory segment. But how do we know if all the memory has been used up and more needs to be reallocated? We need a new variable to keep track of that:

```
int counter = 0;
```

I've initialized `counter` to 0 as nothing has been written into `years`.

Now, we can add the user input into the array just after

```
printf("Enter a year: "); scanf("%d", &y);
```

by using

```
years[counter] = y;
counter++; /* Increment counter */
```

`counter` needs to be incremented so that we know that the first slot has been used and the next free slot is 1. But...What happens when the user enters more than 10 years? Data will be written to invalid memory locations invoking a phenomenon called [*Undefined Behavior*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior)(UB). The consequences of UB can be terrifying. So, it is best that you avoid it at all costs!

We need to allocate more memory when the user wishes to enter more than 10 years. `realloc`(from `stdlib.h`) is a function which you can use to allocate more memory. Just add

```
if(counter == size)
{
    int* temp = years; /* Backup in case realloc fails */
    size += 10; /* Which is the same as `size = size + 10` */
    years = realloc(years, size * sizeof(int)); /* realloc size(20) memory */

    if(years == NULL) /* If realloc failed */
    {
        printf("reallocing memory failed");
        years = temp; /* years is NULL, retrieve the original contents */
        break; /* Break out of the loop */
    }
}
```

before the code that writes the user input to `years`, i.e, before

```
years[counter] = y;
counter++; /* Increment counter */
```

Ok. Now, Our program can handle more than 10 years when the user wishes to. But something is missing. Ah. We need to print the inputs after the loop. Simply add the following code

```
int i;
for(i = 0; i < counter; i++)
    leapYear(years[i]);
```

just after the loop to print the results.

Finally, we need to free the allocated memory so that there will not be a memory leak. Add

```
free(years);
```

just after the loop where you print the results, i.e, just after

```
int i;
for(i = 0; i < counter; i++)
    leapYear(years[i]);
```

---

## Full Program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void leapYear (int year) /* Why does this function return an int? */
{
    if ((year % 4 == 0 && year % 100 != 0) || year % 400 == 0)
        printf("%d is a leap year\n", year);
    else
        printf("%d is not a leap year\n", year);
    /* return 0; Function's return type is now changed to void */
}

int main()
{
    int* years, size = 10, counter = 0, i, input, ch; 

    years = malloc(sizeof(int) * size); /* Or years = malloc(size * sizeof *years); */

    if(years == NULL) /* If malloc failed */
    {
        printf("malloc failed to allocate memory");
        return -1; /* Exit the program */
    }

    do
    {
        printf("Enter your choice \n 1. Enter a year\n 2. Exit\n ");
        scanf("%d", &ch);          
        switch (ch)
        {
            case 1:
                printf("Enter a year: ");
                scanf("%d", &input);

                if(counter == size)
                {
                    int* temp = years; /* Backup in case realloc fails */
                    size += 10; /* Which is the same as `size = size + 10` */
                    years = realloc(years, size * sizeof(int)); /* realloc space for size(20) ints */

                    if(years == NULL) /* If realloc failed */
                    {
                        printf("reallocing memory failed");
                        years = temp; /* years is NULL, retrieve the original contents */
                        ch = 2; /* For breaking out of the loop */
                        break; /* Break out of the switch-case */
                    }
                }

                years[counter] = input;
                counter++; /* Increment counter */

                leapYear(input);
               /* break; Not required */
            /* case 2: ... This isn't required */
        }
    } while (ch != 2);

    printf("\n\n"); /* Printing some newlines */

    for(i = 0; i < counter; i++)
        leapYear(years[i]);

    free(years);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

 int main() {

int year,A,B,C;

printf("Enter the value of year :");
scanf("%d",&year);

A = year%4;

B = year%100;

C = year%400;

 if(((A==0) && (B!=0)) || (C==0))


 {

 printf("The year is Leap year");

 }

 else

 {

 printf("The year is't Leap year");

 }

return 0;

}
```

Comment: Usually it's a good idea to add some explanation to your answer.

Comment: The line `C==o` does not compile. Furthermore, it does not answer the question (particularly, "the program will then display all the years entered and will write if the year is leap or not". Furthermore, it does not add anything new - the algorithm it shows is already mentioned in the other answers.

Comment: C==o isn't correct ; C==0 it is correct ,it was typing mistake!